# When does $scope come into existence?

Tags: angularjs

This question was asked to me in an interview and I really got blank there. So when an Angular app is started, at which point in its bootstrapping phase, the "$scope" object becomes usable?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: More precise link : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle